# customizer not working when ever i activate ssl

Tags: theme-customizer, ssl

when ever i activate my free ssl from cloudflare my websites customizer not working it is showing me blank page. please help.

screen shot
[image]

Console Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Open DevTools (press F12), refresh the page and show console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Cloudflare's flexible SSL then you will run in to issues with WordPress. From my basic understanding, this is because Cloudflare's flexible SSL doesn't offer end-to-end encryption, it essentially encrypts items between the client and Cloudflare, but not from Cloudflare to your server.

Because of this, WordPress won't always serve up the files in https:// format, so I have simply used a plugin in the past... If you search `Cloudflare Flexible SSL` in WordPress plugins then you should find a plugin that, once activated, will fix those issues that you're getting.